# Wrong small cap title in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, small-caps

In what follows, I do not know why the "a" of the appendix in the toc is not a small cap?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{kpfonts}      
\DeclareRobustCommand{\capsspacing}{\scshape\MakeLowercase}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}                
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\normalfont}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\capsspacing}%
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}%      
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be changing the value of `\cftchappresnum` not `\cftchapfont`

Your MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{kpfonts}      
\DeclareRobustCommand{\capsspacing}{\scshape\MakeLowercase}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}                
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\capsspacing}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}%
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}%      
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

What I believe was happening was that `\cftchappresnum` was set to `\normalfont`, causing the `\scshape` portion to be overridden.  So you were left essentially with a `\MakeLowercase` giving you the lowercase "a" and a small caps chapter title.  If you comment out the `\cftchappresnum` command, you would see that both the appendix "A" and the chapter title were small-caps.  If that's what you wanted then just remove the `\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\capsspacing}` line in the MWE I've provided.

Otherwise, this now sets the prechapter section numbering to `\scshape\MakeLowercase` and then before the chapter title, changes it back to `\normalfont`